# Gparted + dual boot - no ability to install windows on a partitioncreated with it

Tags: dual-boot, gparted

I am at day 4 of trying to dualboot.

I have used Gpart to create a windows partition as per this article: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1627197

However when I load windows, it says " Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate existing system partition..

Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest to install Windows first, if you have the option you should let the Ubuntu installer do most of this work for you. The installer is very intuitive with many special options for computers with windows already installed on it.

For my current build I dedicated most of my HDD to Windows because I know I can put my media on it and share it across the 2 OS's easily.

If you still want to go with installing Ubuntu first it will take you much more troubleshooting and fiddling with tools like Samba (for file sharing between Linux and Windows).

Comment: Thanks, I have been able to get something going, really looking forward to my ubuntu experience, as I love being in console. For the record, I was installing windows first.